# Random Variable vs Probability

Tags: measure-theory

My understanding is that a random variable $X$ maps $ω \in \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $P$ maps $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0, 1]$.

What is the relationship between the mapping $X$ and the mapping $P$? Is there no relationship? Do we ever care about the mapping $X$? Or is the mapping $X$ usually assumed to be the identity (i.e. $X(ω) = ω$)?

Also, when we say $P(X=a)$, is $a \in \mathcal{F}$? Or is $a \in X(ω)$? A book I'm reading has the following quote:

> A random variable $X$ is called simple if there is a finite set $\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ such that $X(ω) \in \{x_1,...,x_m\}$ for all $ω$. The expectation of such a random variable is defined by
> $$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{m}x_iP\{X = x_i\}.$$

This makes it seem like in $P(X=a)$, $a \in X(ω)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that a random variable $X$ maps $ω \in \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $P$ maps $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0, 1]$.

Yes.

> What is the relationship between the mapping $X$ and the mapping $P$? Is there no relationship? Do we ever care about the mapping $X$?

Without the probability measure $P$, the mapping $X$ is just a function with no special properties. But together with $P$, we can give a notion of "what is the probability that $X$ is in the interval $[a,b]$?" by applying $P$ to the set $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in [a,b]\}$.

> Or is the mapping $X$ usually assumed to be the identity (i.e. $X(ω) = ω$)?

In light of the definition $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, note that this question does not make if $\Omega \ne \mathbb{R}$

> Also, when we say $P(X=a)$, is $a \in \mathcal{F}$? Or is $a \in X(ω)$?

$P(X = a)$ is a shorthand for $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = a\})$. Note that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = a\}$ is a subset of $\Omega$ (that belongs to $\mathcal{F}$ if $X$ is measurable).

---

Also, you write "$\in X(\omega)$" in your post a few times, which does not make sense. $X(\omega)$ is a real number (you plug in an element $\omega \in \Omega$ to the mapping $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ to get an element of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Technically, even without the probability measure $P$, doesn't $X$ still have the special property of being measurable? i.e. that the pre-image of any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an element of $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @Joe Fair point, that is true

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$X$ cannot be the identity, since in general $\Omega\neq\Bbb R$. More generally the codomain of $X$ need not be $\Bbb R$ but rather any measurable space.

Yes, the probability measure has nothing to do with the mapping $X$. However, do not confuse this with the *probability associated to $X$*. $P(X=a)$ means $P(X^{-1}(a))$- the probability measure of the event containing those $\omega$ for which $X(\omega)=a$ - and more generally for any measurable subset $A\subset\Bbb R$, the probability that $X$ is in $A$, or intuitively - the probability of *observing* an element in the set $A$ - is $P(X^{-1}(A))$.

I there interchanged $P$’s meaning with the probability of the observation and the probability measure on $\Omega$, as is standard, but hopefully now you see the difference.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername You’re very welcome!